# Delete points in a plot until the 2D KDE is everywhere under a certain level

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning, scipy, data-science

Imagine you have a 2d dataset and you want to draw the points in a plot. But there are too many.

With a 2D KDE (kernel density estimation) I can determine the density of the points over all in the dataset. I want to delete points at the densest areas until the kernel density is below a certain value everywhere. How can I do that?

Yes, there are better ways to solve the problem of overplotting, but my problem is a bit different, so I have to do it exactly as described.

Comment: could you provide an example of your dataset ? It'd be helpful I think